# Как написать на python код для возвращения к строке выше?

Tags: python, функции

```
computer = int(input('Привет! Что хотите посмотреть?:достопримечательности и рестораны(1)'))
if computer == 1:

city = input('Введите интересующий город РФ из списка:\nМосква\nСанкт-Питербруг\nНижний Новгород\n')
 city = city.lower()


 if city == 'москва':

    moscow = int(input('Хотите посетить достопримечательности(1) или рестораны(2)?Напишите цифру:'))

   if moscow == 1:

     print('Погуляйте в парке Горького, на Воробьевых горах или в парке Зарядье, парк ВДНХ и посетите ГУМ, попробовав там мороженое =) И не забудьте про Красную площадь')

     enter_m = input('Нравятся ли Вам театры?')

     enter_m = enter_m.lower()

     if enter_m == 'да':

       print('Конечно же "Большой театр" стоит вашего внимания. Также посетите театр «Ленком»')

     elif enter_m == 'нет':

       print('В Москве множество музеев, таких как:\n"Исторический музей" на Красной площади,\n"Дарвиновский музей",\n"Музей Победы",\n"Планетарий Москвы".')

   elif moscow == 2:

     rest_m = input('Ценник средний или высокий?')

     rest_m = rest_m.lower()

     if rest_m == 'средний':

       print('"Igloobar", "Capo", "Иван-чайное купе" - достойные места, где качество оправдывает стоимость')

     elif rest_m == 'высо
кий':
       print('"White Rabbit", "Шикотан", "Harvey & Monica" - вот где ценник точно выше среднего, но не только за красивые глазки)')
      
 city = input('Введите интересующий город РФ из списка:\nМосква\nСанкт-Питербруг\nНижний Новгород\nИЛИ\nвернутся в меню(напишите back)')

 city = city.lower()

 if city == 'back':

# (вот тут надо, чтобы программа возвращалась к первой строке и начала выполнять ее действия)
```

Comment: Оборачивайте код в цикл while, если не city != 'back', то выходите из цикла.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы программа вернулась к первой строке и начала выполнять ее действия, вы можете использовать цикл `while`. Вот код:

```py
while True:
    computer = int(input('Привет! Что хотите посмотреть?: достопримечательности и рестораны(1)'))
    if computer == 1:
        city = input('Введите интересующий город РФ из списка:\nМосква\nСанкт-Питербург\nНижний Новгород\n')
        city = city.lower()
        
        if city == 'москва':
            
            moscow = int(input('Хотите посетить достопримечательности(1) или рестораны(2)? Напишите цифру:'))
            if moscow == 1:
                print('Погуляйте в парке Горького, на Воробьевых горах или в парке Зарядье, парк ВДНХ и посетите ГУМ, попробовав там мороженое =) И не забудьте про Красную площадь')
                enter_m = input('Нравятся ли Вам театры?')
                enter_m = enter_m.lower()
                if enter_m == 'да':
                    print('Конечно же "Большой театр" стоит вашего внимания. Также посетите театр «Ленком»')
                elif enter_m == 'нет':
                    print('В Москве множество музеев, таких как:\n"Исторический музей" на Красной площади,\n"Дарвиновский музей",\n"Музей Победы",\n"Планетарий Москвы".')
            elif moscow == 2:
                rest_m = input('Ценник средний или высокий?')
                rest_m = rest_m.lower()
                if rest_m == 'средний':
                    print('"Igloobar", "Capo", "Иван-чайное купе" - достойные места, где качество оправдывает стоимость')
                elif rest_m == 'высокий':
                    print('"White Rabbit", "Шикотан", "Harvey & Monica" - вот где ценник точно выше среднего, но не только за красивые глазки)')
        
        city = input('Введите интересующий город РФ из списка:\nМосква\nСанкт-Питербург\nНижний Новгород\nИЛИ\nвернуться в меню (напишите back)')
        city = city.lower()
        
        if city == 'back':
            continue  # Продолжаем цикл и возвращаемся к первой строке
```

надеюсь дядя Nymos тебе помог!